# Easy task, windows prompt batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, eps

I am a Windows 7 User who wants to convert multiple *.eps files to pdf-files. Therefore I installed a program called EPSPDF.rb. 
I integrated it into my systempath which makes me use it in the command prompt like this:

```
C:\TEMP>epspdf somefile.eps
```

The program converts somefile.eps to somefile.pdf.
What I am trying to achieve now is writing a Windows Batch File which will look in
the directory C:\TEMP for all *.eps files and convert them all.

I am still trying hard since I am quite unfamiliar with the programming language.
I guess writing the few lines will be an easy issue for someone who is familiar with Batch Files in Windows. I will be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%f in (*.eps) do epspfd %%f
```

This is for use in a batch file. You can run it right on the command prompt, only you need to use `%f` instead of `%%f`. Just because. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for %F in (*.eps) do epspdf %F
```